# C# Sorting a list of objects, according to multiple(26+3) categories in a specific order (LINQ, if else, switch case)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, sorting

I have a list of objects I am trying to sort/order according to a specific list of categories. The categories themselves are different string arrays (26 of them / string[] {"W", "U" }) and the extras are regular conditions like name(string), type (string), cost(int). I should either order the list in one go, or as I have partially done now would be to prepare 26 if statements/switch cases and create 26 sub lists that I will individually sort by name, type, cost and then merge into a bigger endResult list.

```
string[] {"W", "U" }
...
string[] {"R", "G", "W", "U" }
```

As the order of the 26 categories is fixed I considered using switch case, but I cannot use a string array as a switch expression. Writing 26 if statements seems like a rather crude way to do this (not to mention actually writing it), but at this point this is the only way I could make this work. I also tried cr

The sorting by name, type (string attribute of the object), cost(int value) should be no problem in the divided sorting but if I do it in one go I have to integrate it in the main sorting function.

So I was wondering, is there a better way to tackle this? Could I somehow make an elaborate LINQ query that would make sure the priorities are followed?

Thank you in advance for any tips!

**EDIT**: As this was closed for needing clarification I try to elaborate it more.

The objects have an attribute that is color_identity which is a string array.

```
private string[] color_identity;
```

In the sorting, I have to check if this field is the same as one of the 26 sorting categories such as:

```
               new string[] {"W", "U" },
               new string[] {"W", "B" },
               new string[] {"U", "B" },
               new string[] {"U", "R" },
...
               
               new string[] {"W", "U", "B" },
               new string[] {"U", "B", "R" },
               new string[] {"B", "R", "G" },
...

               new string[] {"R", "G", "W", "U" },
               new string[] {"U", "B", "R", "G" },
               new string[] {"B", "R", "G", "W" },
...

               new string[] {"W", "U", "B", "R", "G" }
```

The order of elements in the result list should be based on the order of these categories.
Is it possible to filter/sort the List of objects in one go, if yes then how?
Or should I just break it down to 26 queries? Is there a way to make it more dynamic and not as repetitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made an extension method for this

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CustomSort<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> input,
    Func<T, TKey> getKey,
    params TKey[] order)
{
    var valueDict = input.ToDictionary(item => getKey(item));
    for (int i = 0; i < order.Length; i++) {
        if (valueDict.TryGetValue(order[i], out T item)) {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

`getKey` is a lambda returning the key by which you want to sort your objects. These keys in the input must be unique in this implementation. So, I don't know if this will be useful for your scenario. My scenario was to sort objects containing a column information by column name using a custom order.

Usage:

```
var order = new string[] {"R", "G", "W", "U" };
var sorted = input.CustomSort(obj => obj.Key, order);
```

or, because of the `params` array:

```
var sorted = input.CustomSort(obj => obj.Key, "R", "G", "W", "U");
```

---

Example:

```
class C
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
var a = new C[] {
    new C { Key = "A", Name = "John" },
    new C { Key = "B", Name = "Ann" },
    new C { Key = "C", Name = "Max" }
};
var result = a.CustomSort(c => c.Key, "B", "C", "A")
    .Select(c => c.Name);
```

yields: Ann, Max, John

Here, the `Key` property must have unique values, the `Name` property not. The whole value of `Key` must match. But of course you could write `c => c.Key[0]` to compare only the first character of the key. (But this character must be unique)

If you have non-unique keys, you could group by key

```
var result = a
    .GroupBy(c => c.Key)
    .CustomSort(g => g.Key, "B", "C", "A")
    .Select(g => g.ToList());
```

or, if you want to order by the first character: `.GroupBy(c => c.Key[0])`.

Comment: Hey @Olivier! Does this code use the whole {"R", "G", "W", "U" } array as a value to compare or the characters represent the order itself? Regarding the uniqueness of the keys in the input, do you mean that the attribute's value itself should be unique? Sorry if the question seems strange; I'm relatively new to programming so advanced concepts can be a bit challenging for me at first.

Comment: It's not a matter of programming in general. The required uniqueness is because the way I implemented this method (it is adding the keys to a dictionary). See the example I added.

Comment: Now I understand! Your second example helped a lot (and I probably needed a good night sleep too...). Yes, the uniqueness is necessery in my example as well so this fits perfectly but I can use your group by key example in another problem later as well. I tested your version and adapted it to my string arrays and both worked just fine. Now I will be adapting the logic to my class and code and have learned something really useful! Merci @Olivier! :)